# How can I pause a YouTube video when a button is clicked with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, iframe, slider, youtube-api

I have a jQuery slider (mostly identical to the http://slidesjs.com one). I haven't had luck finding an answer to the question of how to pause the "current" or visible slide's YouTube video when the "next" or "previous" button is pressed while also changing the slide itself. I'm using YouTube's iFrames instead of the old embed code, too.

Is there a way to achieve this function with the iFrames? I know that the Anything Slider ( http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/ ) boasts the ability to stop videos, but I'm not sure how it's achieved.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8083093) sounded like it would work, but I'm not sure how to tie it in with an event to set off the video pause function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to integrate youtube api with anythingslider.
http://code.google.com/intl/tr-TR/apis/youtube/overview.html

Comment: @salt I believe the YouTube API is already built into Anything Slider. However, I'm trying to do it separately on a slider based off of the slidesjs.com slider. I've seen the API pages already.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [enable JS API](http://code.google.com/intl/fi-FI/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html) for your player.

After that you can use `player.pauseVideo()` to pause the video.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('iframe').each(function(i,e){
    let iframeSrc = $(e).attr('src');
    $(e).attr('src',iframeSrc);
});
```

This will reset src for all videos, you can modify it to target only one

```
let iframeSrc = $('.youtube_video').attr('src');
$('.youtube_video').attr('src',iframeSrc);
```

Replace the class '.youtube_video' with your actual iframe class