# Stop YouTube video from playing when closing acoordion div

Tags: jquery, css, video, html, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pause a YouTube player when hiding the iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667882/how-to-pause-a-youtube-player-when-hiding-the-iframe)

I have a jquery accordion which plays youtube videos. How can I stop the youtube video from playing when I close the layer? It keeps on playing in the background.

I think I just have to add something tiny to the code but am completely puzzled unfortunately.

Here is my example and the code:
http://defroster.99k.org/youtube_div.htm

Thanks a million for help!
Marcus

Comment: this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128535/stop-a-youtube-video-with-jquery) should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".accordion2 h3").eq(40).addClass("active");
    $(".accordion2 p").eq(40).show();
    $(".accordion2 h3").click(function(){
        var video = $(".accordion2 h3.active").next().children();
        var src = video.attr("src");
        video.attr("src","");
        video.attr("src",src);
        $(this).next("p").slideToggle("slow")
        .siblings("p:visible").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).siblings("h3").removeClass("active");
    });
});​
```

Example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/r8h7t/20/

Comment: You are the man!! Works brilliantly. Thanks so much. How can I thank you?

Comment: It even works in an old version of internet explorer. Nice job!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#the-accordion").accordion({
    changestart: function(){
        player.stopVideo();
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong but the code will not display nicely. See below