# opening Jquery dialog after destroying it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a youtube video appear in the jquery dialog box, so if it is playing while the dialog window is closed, it will remain playing behind the scenes.

What I do as a result is destroy the window when it is closed:

```
    $("#gallery_reel").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 540,
            close: function() {
                $(this).dialog('destroy');
            }
    });
```

But once the dialog box is destroyed, it won't open again unless I refresh the page. How do I reopen the dialog box?

Comment: You can just close it and not destroy `.dialog('close')`

Comment: when I close it, the video is still playing in the background.

Comment: @steeped looks like you need to know how to stop the video from playing before closing the dialog, then. Are you using a video player API? Or just HTML5 video? Destroy is not a good method, because, in order to open the object you'll have to reinstantiate it, which causes a fair amount of unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128535/stop-a-youtube-video-with-jquery

Comment: Why not use the close function callback to just stop the youtube video?

Comment: @SpYk3HH how do I callback the video?

Comment: stop the video then use `.detach()`. see if this can help you: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/ppDat/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would SUGGEST just using the close function to STOP the [youtube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035908/opening-jquery-dialog-after-destroying-it/13036027#answer-13035984), but if you insist on other, instead of destroy try the following:

> **Non-preferred** (will copy html into a newly emptied dialog)

```
$("#gallery_reel").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 540,
    close: function() {
        var inrHTML = $(this).html();
        $(this).empty().html(inrHTML);
    }
});
```

> **Should be better Method** (Based on the thought that most "embeded youtube" vids are in Iframes, i think

```
$("#gallery_reel").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 540,
    close: function() {
        $(this).find("iframe").get(0).stopVideo();
    }
});
```

Comment: the close function does not stop the youtube video.

Comment: No but this should inevitably remove the original HTML inside your dialog and replace it with a copy of the original html, thus the video should be stopped, so to speak

Answer (score 0):

To stop the Youtube video:

```
$('#playerID').get(0).stopVideo();
```

from [Stop a youtube video with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128535/stop-a-youtube-video-with-jquery)

Comment: what would my player id be, as I am using the iframe embed code Youtube provides me with?

Answer (score 0):

this is because when you "destroy" you pop the mapped var off of the jQuery stack.

```
varname = new $("#gallery_reel").dialog(.....);
```

would pop it back onto the stack

Question here is do you need to destroy or just close the dialog.

proper use of variables and a cleanup when they leave the page instead of closing the dialog  could fix this