# Modal Popup with Video, Keeps Playing Audio after Closed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a pop-up video button on my website.
But when i close it, or click on a modal-out space, the audio still continues.

How can i solve this problem?
I tried some javascript function, but i think im doing something wrong...

Thanks!

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="button" id="myBtn">Watch Video</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <span class="close">×</span>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QH2-TGUlwu4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613303/youtube-video-still-playing-when-bootstrap-modal-closes

Comment: it does not work, i did research before i posted this question

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest way for you is to re-assign the iframe video src value so that it resets itself and stops. E.g. Assign your iframe an id of example `id="yplayer"` and then use the following statement where you want to stop and reload the video.

```
document.getElementById('yplayer').src = document.getElementById('yplayer').src;
```

The second option is to use the youtube api functions which will involve a little more code handling. [Youtube API Docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the documentation for html audio/video on https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_pause.asp

I suggest you change

```
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

with the following code

```
span.onclick = function stopVideo() {
     document.getElementById('video').pause();
}
```