# html5 video keeps playing in background after bootstrap modal closes

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So after reading this post ([Twitter Bootstrap Modal stop Youtube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799377/twitter-bootstrap-modal-stop-youtube-video)), I still can't get this solution to work. I've tried verious other methods but still no luck. I guess if my coding isn't so sloppy this would be working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated Thanks all..

```
 <!-- Item line a tin -->
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">

           <h3 >How Line a Tin</h3>
           <a class="vid-lib"><p><button data-toggle="modal"  href="#video-player" onclick="return false;"  class="btn btn-primary btn-large"><span><img src="vid/thumb/line_tin.jpg" style="width:100%;"/></span></button></p></a>

       <div id="video-player" class="modal fade" style="display: none;">
         <div class="video-content">

         <div class="video-header">
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal" style="color: #000000;">X close</a>
            <h3 style="color:#f20573;"><span><img src="img/ask_helen.png" style="width:15%;"/></span> How to Line a tin</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="video-body">
         <iframe width="1000" height="600" style="margin: 0 auto;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LtznQ3XI280" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="video-footer">
            <p>&copy; 2015 Fashionable Fondants. All Rights Reserved</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
           <a  href="vid/line_tins.mp4" download="Linning_a_tin" class="btn" style="margin: auto;">Download Tutorial</a>
    </div> <!-- End Item  -->
```

```
    <script> jQuery(".modal-backdrop, #video-player .close, #video-player .btn").live("click", function() { jQuery("#video-player iframe").attr("src", jQuery("#video-player iframe").attr("src")); }); </script>
```

Comment: i had this problem and my solution was to remove the player whan modal was closed and add it when modal was open

Comment: Are you really using `live()`??? Which jq version? Error in console?

Comment: @A.Wolf- i'm using "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js". also do I change live() to on()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#video-player').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
  $('.video-body iframe')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"stopVideo","args":""}', '*'); 
})
```

Comment: thanks for this, unfortunately it still has no impact. Where is best practice to put the script, in other posts they say in the body<> but then some say to put it in the head<>. thanks for the quick reply

Comment: Awesome got it working!! thank you loads. I never changed the id in the script you provided :-).