# flow page over current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have seen an amazing  thing when surfing this website:

http://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates/page202/flat-theme

When you click on **live demo**, it opens another page over the current page without redirecting or opening another window.

I wanted to make the same thing on my website, and I have tried a lot of things, but none work. Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: Add your codes too. Let us see what you tried .. we will help you with ur code.. or make fiddle

Comment: Try using the 'modal' in Bootstrap framework. You can alter the dimension of the modal. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Comment: It's because you are not asking for an answer, you are asking for a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking about iframe, You can read more about it [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp)

and about the popup you can use [Bootstrap Modal](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)

Here is a 
[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/aya_salama/pen/JRWEap) for what you want so you can try it

code:

```css
.btn {
    margin: 20px;
}
.modal-content {
    width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <!-- this is where you got the other page you want to show -->
.        <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp" height="500" width="750">
        
        </iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you i had figured it out put a new problem accord i wanted to embed a video in the modal and the problem is when the modal fade out the video continue to play ??

Comment: @aghedaljlad i add another answer for this please check it

Answer (score 1):

The example you are talking about is loaded through an `iframe`. See an example below:

```html
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
```

I would guess the reason you normally get downvoted is because you pay no attention whatsoever to make your question nicely formatted or even correctly spelled.

Also, this is very basic knowledge. You can find documentation on it all over the web. There is absolutely no reason to ask the question again, so naturally people downvote you.

Comment: and i was looking for  more than five days and couldn't find anything

Comment: Well, do a search for ["how to embed webpage into html"](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20embed%20webpage%20into%20html&rct=j), and there's no need to be angry anymore

Answer (score 1):

About your Problem with video 
Try to add this code to your js

```
$("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $("#myModal iframe").attr("src", $("#myModal iframe").attr("src"));
});
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/aya_salama/pen/ZpZZzJ)

you can find more info in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799377/twitter-bootstrap-modal-stop-youtube-video)

Comment: thank you again @Aya your answers have been a great help for me