# jquery not working in ie (any) but working in all other browsers

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Hi I have a bit of code which works with Jquery and works perfectly in all browsers except ie (and it doesn t seem to work in any ie browsers -7, 8, 9).
The Jquery code is as follows.. can anyone see a problem:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var obj = $('object')
     .wrap('<div id="test"></div>')
     .find('embed').attr('src', function (i, s) { return s + '&enablejsapi=1&version=3' }).end()
     .find('param[name=movie]').attr('value', function (i, v) { return v + '&enablejsapi=1&version=3' }).end()
     .detach()
     .appendTo($('#test'));

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#emsbinstartbutton").click(function () {
                    //Then assign the src to null, this then stops the video been playing
                    obj.find('embed')[0].pauseVideo();
                    $("body").append($("<div>").css({
                        position: "fixed"
        , width: "640px"
        , height: "425px"
        , "background-color": "#000"
        , opacity: 0.6
        , "z-index": 999
        , top: 0
        , left: 0
                    }).attr("id", "page-cover"));

                    $("#threebytwo").show();
                });
            });
```

This code makes a widget pop up when a user clicks a buy now button:

```
 $("#threebytwo").show();
```

Here is a jsfiddle of the whole code which you can see wokring in Firfox chrome and safari but not working in ie.

http://jsfiddle.net/M46rZ/5/

I looked this up and saw a trick where you set the meta data tag to ie 8 but i have tried this but it hasn t worked.

I think i need to read up a bit more on cross browser issues as i keeep coming across them but nay help is appreciated!

**Edit**
Sorry to clarify what the actual problem is - when you click the buy now button there should be a pop up

**Edit 2**

as pointed out in one of the comments it is this line which stop the code working in ie:

```
obj.find('embed')[0].pauseVideo();
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have a `$(document).ready()` inside a `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Plus, it doesn't work for me in Chrome24. I get, `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLEmbedElement> has no method 'pauseVideo'`

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Nothing happens? The wrong thing happens? Any errors in the console?

Comment: also works for me in IE 8, even if i use compatibility mode.

Comment: it works fine after I commented out `obj.find('embed')[0].pauseVideo();`

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko your right i have updated my jsfiddle to only have the one document ready

Comment: @Dygestor your right that does make it work but i do need the video to pause when the buy now button is clicked any idea why this doesn t work in ie?

Comment: @nnnnnn i ve updated the question with the actual problem

Comment: it looks like quite a few people had the same problem like you do.. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128535/stop-a-youtube-video-with-jquery) maybe you could try some of these solutions

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle, there is a trailing space in the video param:

```
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/fBZTbCrM2eQ&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1&wmode=opaque ">
```

which after your js manipulation becomes:

```
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/fBZTbCrM2eQ&hl=en_US&fs=1&wmode=opaque &enablejsapi=1&version=3">
```

I'm not sure if that should be enough to break things for the browsers using the `<object>` rather than the `<embed>`, but it could be worth trying to remove.

I tried removing the space in your fiddle but for some strange reason that edit refused to take effect.