# Why my youtube video does not stop?

Tags: php, jquery, youtube

Here is my code :-

```
<?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM era_videos ORDER BY video_id";
            $sqlex = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

            $m = 1;

            while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlex))
            {


        ?>
                <div class="slide" current_id="<?php echo $m;?>" style="width:300px !important; height:200px !important;">
                    <object class="youtube" id="videoid<?php echo $m;?>" width="300" height="200"><param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/v/<?php echo $result['urlname'];?>"version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0">    </param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="https://www.youtube.com/v/<?php echo $result['urlname'];?>"version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="300" height="200" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>
                </div>
       <?php
                $m++;
            }
       ?>
```

jQuery Code :-

```
jQuery('#iCarouselNext').click(function()
      {
         var current_id = parseInt($('.current').attr('current_id'));

         var previous_id = current_id - 1;

         $('#videoid'+previous_id).stopVideo();


      });
```

But it throws an error - `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'stopVideo'`

I found this but no solution [Stop a youtube video with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128535/stop-a-youtube-video-with-jquery)

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$('#videoid'+previous_id).get(0).stopVideo();`

Comment: or `$('#videoid'+previous_id)[0].stopVideo();`

Comment: tried both but not working

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('#videoid'+previous_id).get(0).stopVideo();
```

Or

```
$('#videoid'+previous_id)[0].stopVideo();
```

Also there is an error in your logic of getting the current_id

```
var current_id = parseInt($('.current').attr('current_id'));
```

This will always give the first element's id.

Comment: Where to give this id ? I have given the id to object tag