# Stop previous video from playing when clicking on other thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need some help.

How this works:

Every thumbnail will play a different video. However when i click any thumbnail, and play the video and then i switch to another thumbnail, the previous video still plays at the background.

How can i make it in such a way that, every video will auto restart when click on every respective thumbnail?

You can refer to the codepen below. Any help will be appreciated. Thankyou.

```
Refer to codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdOEpd
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?csw=1#Playback_controls

Comment: Try this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoXbKg

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128535/stop-a-youtube-video-with-jquery